# Effective range of google sheet filter is limited

Tags: google-sheets, filtering

I am working with a 400-row sheet and would like to filter on certain cell attributes, but I find that the filter works correctly for the top portion of the sheet (Up to row 50 or so) but then fails to filter any of the remaining rows, behaving as if no filter exists for the remainder of the sheet.

Steps to Reproduce.

1. Open sheet
2. Data...Remove Filter
3. Click into cell A1
4. Data...Create a Filter
5. Click dropdown in column E and select filter by color...yellow
6. Click Save

Expected Result:  Only rows that have yellow-highlighted cells are displayed.

Actual Result:  Rows in range 1-50 are filtered correctly.  Rows > 50 are displayed regardless of color of cell in col E.

Answer (score 1):

In their instructions Google Docks Editors Help → [Sort & Filter your data](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681?hl=en) → Filter your data, Google say to "select a range of cells" [or] "right click on a cell or a range of cells."

They don't say why, but what one is doing by pre-selecting cells is explicitly choosing the range on which to check the filter. Mismatches outside that range will fail the conditions to be filtered since they're out of range, and will thus not be hidden. In your steps to reproduce, you "3. Click into cell A1," which is neither selecting a range of cells nor right clicking on a cell or range of cells.

What Sheets does in response to this is apparently that it tries to guess what range was intended. In my limited testing, it seems to seek out a contiguous block of populated cells? After your step 4, you can see some columns turn green and rows auto-selected. I'd surmise you could scroll down and see it has seen fit to select about 50 rows before it finds an empty cell somewhere or hits some other secret logical condition and calls it off. This auto-selection is the range it will filter.

To fix its bad assumption, I'd replace your step

3. Click into cell A1

with

3. Click the header to select all cells in column E